# assembly intel x86 call function with local variables

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I'm having an issue with a binary search implementation. Note, I do not want to modify this c code, I'm trying to translate it to assembly. Here's my c code:

```
int binary_search_c(int n, int list[], int low, int high) {
int middle;

    if (low > high)
        return -1;

    middle = (low + high)/2;

    if (n == list[middle])
        return middle;
    if (n < list[middle]) {
        high = middle - 1;
    } else {
        low = middle + 1;
    }

    return binary_search_c(n, list, low, high);
}
```

And here is my binary search in assembly. I've commented NEW with things I've added for the first time, so possible problem areas, though I'm pretty sure my problem lies in bin.

```
;* int binary_search(int n, int list[], int low, int high);                *
;*****************************************************************************
%define n [ebp+8]
%define list [ebp+12]
%define low [ebp+16]
%define high [ebp+20]
binary_search:
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp

    sub esp, 4      ;one local var                    |
%define middle [ebp-4] ; define local var as middle   | NEW
    mov eax, low  ; pull low into register
    cmp eax, high ; compare low to high low > high
    jle less;    ; if less than or greater, go to less  
    mov eax, -1  ; move -1 into eax for return
    jmp return; ; call return/end function


less:               ;if low is not > high
    mov eax, low    ;move middle into register
    add eax, high   ;high+low
    mov ebx, 2      ;move 2 into ebx for div
    xor edx, edx    ;clear edx                        |
    xor eax, eax                      
    div ebx         ; div eax, by 2 =>(low+high)/2    | NEW
    mov middle, eax ;move (low+high)/2 into middle   
    mov eax, n      ; move middle into eax
    mov edi, list   ; move list into edi for list call
    mov edx, middle ; move middle into edx as list index |
    lea esi, [edi+edx*4] ; grab list[middle]             |
    mov ebx, [esi]      ; move list[middle] into register| NEW
    cmp eax, ebx  ; compare n and list[middle]             
    jne notE;     ; if not equal (n ==list[middle]
    mov eax, middle ;move middle into eax for return
    jmp return;   ;call return/end function

notE:       ;if n !=list[middle]
    mov eax, n  ;move eax into n
    mov edi, list ; move list into edi to access list
    mov ebx, middle ; move middle into ebx as index |
    lea esi, [edi+ebx*4] ; grab list[middle]        |
    mov ebx, [esi] ;move list[middle] into ebx      |NEW
    cmp eax, ebx   ; compare n and list[middle]
    jge .else;     ; if greater than or equal n < list[middle]
    mov eax, middle ;move middle into eax for return
    sub eax, 1     ;middle-1
    mov ebx, high  ; put high into ebx for replacement
    mov ebx, eax  ; high = middle-1
    jmp bin;     ;jump to next part[not return]


.else:     ;if n >= list[middle]
    mov eax, middle ;move middle into eax to add 1
    add eax, 1     ; middle+1
    mov ebx, low   ;move low into ebx for change in low
    mov ebx, eax   ;low = middle+1
bin:         ; final return
    mov eax, high ; move high into eax for push
    push eax   ; push high
    mov ebx, low ;low into ebx
    push ebx  ; push low
    mov ecx, list ; list for push
    push ecx ;push list
    mov edx, n ;n for push
    push edx ;push n                 |
    call binary_search ; call search |
    add esp, 16 ; add 16=>(4*4) to stack for reset | NEW

return:  ;end function
    leave
    ret
```

So after chopping my code up while trying to find the error, I'm getting a seg fault when trying to run anything using `bin`

I think I may be doing something wrong with the addition to the stack with `add esp, 16` though I'm not sure as it's the first time I've called a function with so many arguments and with a local variable at hand. 
I'll gladly take any optimization to my code, I'm just weary about the things labeled NEW, and I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong in bin that throws a fault, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try asking a compiler. :) In other words, compile the C code, and then look at the generated assembly as a reference. Compile without optimization, and perhaps in list mode to keep the C code around.

Comment: FYI divide by 2 is a right-shift, no need to use div

Comment: @barny I have trouble understanding shifts, is there anything wrong with using `div` here?

Comment: div seems like overkill.

Comment: I have, for the add esp, the code shows ` 134: 83 c4 10              add    esp,0x10` when running `ld -m elf_i386 -s -o CCODENAME` this is what I do, which confuses me @unwind

Comment: @barny it helps me understand when I'm not just dividing by 2.

Comment: Have you tested it with a very short list or data designed so the recursive call isn't needed?

Comment: It is a binary search, divide by 2 is sort of implicit. Or are you going to extend it to trinary/quaternary? Oh no, quaternary would just be two shifts.

Comment: @barny no, I'm just trying to implement the c code as is, recursion call and all. I think the problem lies where I `sub esp, 4` at the start for space for middle, the with the `add esp, 16` I feel like I'm missing on that 4, I'm just not sure

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple function that takes four parameters and has a local variable, does something simple that you can check the return value, and returns - got that working?

Comment: The data you give your function determines whether it recurses. Maybe the recursion is the problem? At the moment you just "have a problem" - by testing carefully you can maybe pin that down to "I have a problem when the recursive call is made" (or not). It's called debugging - apply selected data, apply brain logic, find a symptom, build a hypothesis, test that hypothesis, eliminate some possibilities, home in on the actual problem...

Comment: @Monkleys [The `DIV` opcode has much higher latency and much lower throughput than `SHR`.](https://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf) If you prefer to use `DIV` for the sake of readability, you would be better off just writing your code in C and letting the compiler optimise it for you.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage alright, I'll look at using a shift. Though, with or without, my problem still remains, any input on that?

Comment: So reduce the potential sources of problems - START by ensuring that you can call an assembler function with no parameters, extend that by adding a return value, extend that to a function that takes four parameters and returns a value based in some simply way on the parameters, then add a local variable, then add a limited-depth recursive call (you can control this using the input data),.... all these can be done by deleting things from your current code so not difficult.

Comment: `is there anything wrong with using div here`: yes, it's about 30 times slower, and much less convenient (no immediate operand, and has to use edx:eax).

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, I'll look at using a shift. Could you have a look at `bin`, do you see anything wrong with the way I handle `esp add, 16`?
if I say add `esp add, 4`, `call binary_search` then `esp add, 16` my seg fault is gone. But the output is very wrong.

Comment: You would probably better re-insert the `xor eax, eax` instruction in the original question, else it becomes less obvious why you asked in the first place!

Comment: IDK.  The obvious thing I see is that you clobber your caller's EBX, EDI, and ESI (without saving/restoring).  You can easily avoid most of your uses of all three by using addressing modes directly instead of with LEA and MOV.  e.g.  `cmp eax, [edi+edx*4]; compare n and list[middle]`.  You should just keep `list` in EDI the whole time, instead of reloading it from the stack.  C variables can live in registers.  You also have what's probably a bug: `mov ebx, high` followed by `mov ebx, eax` means the `mov ebx, high` had no effect because you overwrite EBX again right away.

Comment: Single-step through your code in a debugger and make sure it's doing what you expect.  Watch the register values change as you step.  See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for some tips on using GDB for asm.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov eax, low    ;move middle into register
> add eax, high   ;high+low
> mov ebx, 2      ;move 2 into ebx for div
> xor edx, edx    ;clear edx                        |
> xor eax, eax    ;clear eax                        |
> div ebx         ; div eax, by 2 =>(low+high)/2    | NEW
> ```

In this code you're trying to calculate the *middle* but you don't really do that because you **zero the EAX register right before the division**!
Please remove the `xor eax, eax` instruction.

---

> ```
> mov ebx, high  ; put high into ebx for replacement
> mov ebx, eax  ; high = middle-1
> jmp bin
> ```

This is a further problem:

You want to setup for the lower partition, but you don't actually store the new *high* index!
This will do it:

```
mov high, eax  ; high = middle-1
jmp bin
```

The same applies to the *low* index.

Comment: Yes, I missed this. Thank you. But, this still doesn't solve my problem. Though it would have been one, thank you.
*edit to reflect

Comment: for your edit, does `mov ebx, eax` not update high? or does it just make a copy of it for use?

Comment: I see, I didn't know this. Thank you. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on the working code, with a `div by 2` instead of a shift, inefficient, by functional. In case anyone else needs it, here:

```
;* int binary_search(int n, int list[], int low, int high);                *
;*****************************************************************************
%define n [ebp+8]
%define list [ebp+12]
%define low [ebp+16]
%define high [ebp+20]
binary_search:
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp

    sub esp, 4      ;one local var
%define middle [ebp-4] ; define local var as middle
    mov eax, low  ; pull low into register
    cmp eax, high ; compare low to high low > high
    jle less;    ; if less than or greater, go to less  
    mov eax, -1  ; move -1 into eax for return
    jmp return; ; call return/end function


less:               ;if low is not > high
    mov eax, low    ;move middle into register
    add eax, high   ;high+low
    mov ebx, 2      ;move 2 into ebx for div
    xor edx, edx    ;clear edx
    div ebx         ; div eax, by 2 =>(low+high)/2
    mov middle, eax ;move (low+high)/2 into middle  
    mov eax, n      ; move middle into eax
    mov edi, list   ; move list into edi for list call
    mov edx, middle ; move middle into edx as list index
    lea esi, [edi+edx*4] ; grab list[middle]
    mov ebx, [esi]      ; move list[middle] into register
    cmp eax, ebx  ; compare n and list[middle]
    jne notE;     ; if not equal (n ==list[middle]
    mov eax, middle ;move middle into eax for return
    jmp return;   ;call return/end function

notE:       ;if n !=list[middle]
    mov eax, n  ;move eax into n
    mov edi, list ; move list into edi to access list
    mov ebx, middle ; move middle into ebx as index
    lea esi, [edi+ebx*4] ; grab list[middle]
    mov ebx, [esi] ;move list[middle] into ebx
    cmp eax, ebx   ; compare n and list[middle]
    jge .else;     ; if greater than or equal n < list[middle]
    mov eax, middle ;move middle into eax for return
    sub eax, 1     ;middle-1
    mov high, eax
    jmp bin;     ;jump to next part[not return]


.else:     ;if n >= list[middle]
    mov eax, middle ;move middle into eax to add 1
    add eax, 1     ; middle+1
       ;move low into ebx for change in low
    mov low, eax   ;low = middle+1

bin:         ; final return
    mov eax, high ; move high into eax for push
    push eax   ; push high
    mov ebx, low ;low into ebx
    push ebx  ; push low
    mov ecx, list ; list for push
    push ecx ;push list
    mov edx, n ;n for push
    push edx ;push n
    call binary_search ; call search
    add esp, 16 ; add 16=>(4*4) to stack for reset


return:  ;end function
    leave
    ret
```

Thank you to @Fifoernik for his answer